# Change security settings of the IE11 using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am getting the error  "Automation server can’t create object error" while creating XLS in IE-11 . I am able to resolve it by doing the following steps

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/237193/Open-Word-Excel-using-JavaScript

Basically here the security setting of the internet explorer is changed . But I want to do this change using java script .

So is it possible to change the internet explorer settings in java script ?

Comment: The answer is fortenately no. That kind of a "security setting" would be totally useles.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing the doubt